# When is the phrase "Guest Recognition Expert" from?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have noticed that some hotels now have jobs for guest recognition experts. Apart from the fact that I find it very hard to understand exactly what it means by just reading its constituent parts, I was wondering when this phrase first came into existence.

Comment: First time I've heard it.  Sounds like something someone in corporate HR dreamed up, analogous to "Sanitation Engineer" for the person who rides on the back of the garbage truck and dumps cans into the truck.  I suppose it means someone who can remember faces and names and give special greetings to returning guests to make them feel valued.

Comment: Based on job ads saying things like "Be a guest recognition expert. Know our regulars by name." it seems to be quite literal in meaning: someone who can remember guests' names and recognise them on sight (which does actually take some effort and skill - there are various tricks for remembering names but some people seem naturally skilled). It's certainly not a common phrase, and you might do better asking somewhere that hospitality experts congregate.

Comment: The two-word collocation ***guest recognition*** doesn't appear *at all* before 2010 in all the tens of millions of books indexed by Google Books. I see that [***9 out of the first 10***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Guest+Recognition%22) results are biochemistry texts referring to *"**Host-Guest Molecular Interactions**".* But there is ***one*** instance in my link that's from a publication called ***Hotel Management and Operations** (2010)*. Personally, I'd say the "hospitality industry" usage somehow got mixed up with a pre-existing (but relatively new) biochemical usage.

Comment: More common: guest recognition specialist. Try that.

Comment: One property lessor has a "Customer Experience Specialist". It's real pupose is to make sure their help desk firewall does its job.

Answer (score 1):

It means someone whose job is to be an expert in recognizing guests of the hotel. Presumably they learn who the guests are, so they can greet them by name. This will give these guests the feeling of being appreciated by the hotel, they're not just nameless, generic customers.

I wouldn't be surprised if this is just a new buzzwordy name for the concierge. Or maybe it's a concierge who is assigned to the higher-paying customers, and expected to provide more personalize service.

This seems to be a pretty recent term, as it doesn't appear at all in the corpus used by Google Ngrams. I'm not sure how to determine when it first came into existence.

I searched for it on LinkedIn, I found one person who listed it as their occupation beginning in 2022. The similar job title "Guest Recognition Specialist" appears in 3 profiles; I only have access to view one of them, and they started the position in 2021.

There were also a number of posts where people wrote

> I’m happy to share that I’m starting a new position as Guest Recognition Specialist

It was interesting to note that they all used similar "I'm happy to share" phrasing. They're all also working for Four Seasons Resorts, but at different locations. So it seems like this may be a position this company invented, and I suspect they encourage their new hires to post this. All the posts were in the past year, again suggesting that it's a recent innovation.

I then searched for Four Seasons's job postings for this position. I found these responsibilities:

> - Answers and directs phone calls, pages, radio requests and faxes in an efficient, courteous and professional manner to achieve maximum
>   customer satisfaction while complying with all Four Seasons' policies
> - Clear suspended profiles, run reports on duplicate profile and merge, run report for global notes submitted and reject/approve, audit
>   incorrect merges, name change and address collection and follow up
>   with required training
> - Maintain historical information and maintain reports that evaluate revenue management performance including source of business, booking
>   pace and geographical analysis
> - Prepare Sales Month End Reports and statistical account production reports using Golden
> - Completes administrative and verification tasks related to guest reservations, employee reservations, call volume, and revenue tracking
> - Coordinates work with and assists other members of theResCom, Front Desk, Finance, and Sales and Marketing teams

Comment: I guess they should also be able to recognise well-known people who have not yet been a guest.

Comment: That sounds more like a celebrity recognition expert. It probably doesn't require as much practice.

Comment: But, per the OP, when did it come into existence?

Comment: Since it doesn't exist in the Google Ngrams corpus, that may be difficult to determine, but suggests it's quite recent.

Comment: Depending on how stringently one conceptualises what it is for a phrase to be in existence, it could even be argued that it hasn't come into existence yet: it may be that it is only being tried out at a few places, and that it still remains to be seen whether it will catch on throughout the industry.

Comment: This answer does not make it clear what kind of recognising is it that the person does. Is the ability to recognise guest by sight essential to the job (as a couple of people who commented below the question assumed), or is that somebody who develops and runs some sort of a programme that recognises frequent quests by providing extra benefits to them (which could be a behind-the-scenes job, that does not involve any direct contact with the guests)?

Comment: @jsw29 I've added the job responsibilities I found in a job posting for guest recognition specialist (I couldn't find one for experts).

Comment: The most important part of this answer is that the phrase appears **only** in the materials of one particular (admittedly very large) company. One can conclude from this that it is not an established part of English language. It is merely a part of the internally used jargon of that company, and nobody who doesn't work for that company should be expected to understand it (and even less to use it).

Comment: Except that they've exposed it to the public in job listings. That's how jargon spreads to an industry and may eventually become part of the general lexicon.